# Boot Menu for Sony VAIO PCG-505ACP Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to access the boot menu to change the boot sequence but don't know what function key is used to do that. I have

Comment: Did you look at the manual for the computer to learn the key for accessing the BIOS or one time Boot Menu?

Comment: Windows boot options are F10. Press repeatedly. Don't hold down.

Comment: The F10 does not work either it just start beeping and then boots into the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Sony model, F10, F11 or the assist key, will get you the boot menu for devices.

[image]

[Source of Information](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779)

Comment: Thanks and I tried that but the F11 does not work and there is no assist on this PC.